# Creating multiple boxes in PHP from MySQL

Tags: php

I have made a **simple** **PHP** news system that just basically **displays** information from a MySQL database that I've made, it also uses CSS for a rounded box, but, I also want it to create multiple rounded boxes displaying different news, so, to sum it up, I just want a code that will create a different box for each result.

Comment: Sure, what have you tried, and what do you mean with 'different' boxes, different in what respect?

Comment: I think that is a good idea, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Currently, all news stories are displayed in one box which annoys me, I want it to create a different box for each result in the MySQL database. Say there was 4 different MySQL results, they're all displayed in one box, I want it to be displayed in 4 boxes, do you understand?

Comment: If that's for me, no problem! @Jack

Comment: Show what you have and then maybe someone will suggest a solution. Currenty there is nowhere to start an answer from!

Comment: I just need a code that will create a new box displaying a MySQL result, the code is in PHP, I really don't think they need the code, the code just displays stuff from MySQL in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your PHP code you will want to put your sql statement within a foreach loop to put each result into their own box.

Here is an easy example:

```
$dbh = db connection
$result = "SELECT new FROM news;";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($result);
$stmt->execute();
$newEach = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($newEach as $val){
    foreach($val as $key=>$news){
        echo '<div class="box">' . $news . '</div>';
    }
}
```

There is probably a better way to get the individual items without having to do a nested foreach but so far I have been unable to find a way that works this well when wanting individual results from a select query.